# Mean of covariance matrices

Tags: covariance, covariance-matrix

I'm trying to generalise a formula that takes the mean of some variances to it work with vectors.

I'm not sure it makes sense to take the variance between a bunch of vectors, rather it is more suited to generate a covariance matrix.

So, is there a way to take the mean of a bunch of covariance matrices?

Comment: Hi, the way the question is written sounds like you might just want to take the arithmetic mean of the matrices (see my answer). However, I have no idea whether this would produce a reasonable generalization of your formula. You might want to add more information, or perhaps post a separate question like 'How to generalise this formula to vectors/multiple dimensions/whatever'.

Comment: Great thanks for your answer, I will post another question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the original covariance matrices are of the same dimension, i.e., you have $n\times n$-matrices $\Sigma_1,\ldots,\Sigma_N$, you could just take the sample mean:
\begin{equation}
\bar{\Sigma} = \frac{1}{N}\left(\Sigma_1 +\ldots+\Sigma_N \right),
\end{equation}
which corresponds to taking elementwise means of the elements of the covariance matrices, i.e., the $i,j$th element will be 
\begin{equation}
\bar{\Sigma}_{i,j} = \frac{\Sigma_{1(i,j)}+\Sigma_{2(i,j)}+\ldots+\Sigma_{N(i,j)}}{N}.
\end{equation}

Provided that the original covariance matrices are valid (positive-semidefinite), this will produce a valid covariance matrix, as positive-semidefiniteness is preserved under summing and multiplying by a positive constant ($1/N$).

Whether taking this mean is reasonable will depend on the context, which is not explained in the question.

Comment: Hey Juho, I've similar problem. I calculate covariance matrix every batch-iterations and I would like to have an estimate, of covariance matrix over several batches. I can't concatenate data, because they come from different time series (but from the same population).